# Google Spreadsheet alternatives

Tags: untagged

I want to replace my company's use of google docs with something I can run on my own server.

Basically our requirements are that we need an online spreadsheet, with a nice easy to use ajax interface, and ideally for it to be open source.

The idea is that it will be easy to collaborate. We don't need real-time collaboration, although it would be nice, I would be happy with a revision controlled wiki style spreadsheet.

I have invesigated the following, but can't quite get them to work right:
 - drupal + sheetnode + revision control (almost does what I want, but a little buggy)
 - wikicalc (too clunky)
 - EditGrid (very nice, however its expensive)

Has anyone else done something like this? Basically all I want is something like dokuwiki, but with a spreadsheet interface. And it needs to be very easy to use so non-techies in the office can figure it out.

Any suggestions are welcome! (It needs to be on our servers, I will not consider hosted options) Thanks.

Comment: Does it really need to be a Web 2.0 solution (as in editing from the browser?).  You might have better luck finding an open-source/Free wiki solution and finding a mechanism to check-out/in any kind of document.

Comment: Why doesn't google docs work for you?  Maybe there is a way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint 2010 won't be cheap, and its not ready. But it will have the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Excel Calculation Services on MOSS 2007

Answer (score 1):

GelSheet (gelsheet.sf.net) from the OpenGoo.org project looks about right. I don't think it's enabled in the OpenGoo demo But you can [see it here.](http://alekan.com/intra/opengoo/public/assets/javascript/gelSheet/interface/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

I am an admin of **Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware**, a full-featured, open source, multilingual, all-in-one Wiki+CMS+Groupware written in PHP.

Tiki was one of the first open source browser-based spreadsheets, back in 2004 ->
tiki.org/article70

We have recently (Tiki5) replaced our spreadsheet front-end with jQuery.sheet for a much nicer user experience ->  visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet

jQuery.sheet is a front-end which is designed to be integrated with a CMS/Wiki/etc. but it is not a full spreadsheet where you can save save data, view history, etc. So you could use Tiki which bundles jQuery.sheet or integrate to another app.

Tiki6 is now in Beta, and offers quite a few enhancements:
http://doc.tiki.org/Spreadsheet+jq#Tiki6_features

As you seem to want an office suite, you'll likely see other goodies :-)
doc.tiki.org/Features

Best regards,

M ;-)

Marc Laporte

P.S. Read more about **Software made the wiki way** at tiki.org/Model

Answer (score 0):

You probably should include Resolver One in your evaluation. It's not open source, but it does allow you to do things like revision control, because it generates Python code for the spreadsheet as you create it. This code can be checked into revision control or audited for correctness. They do have some sort of web server version of it but I don't know the details. Also, because it is build in IronPython, it has easy access to a whole range of .NET addons as well as many pure Python modules. One of their strengths is the ability to keep the data in a central database rather than keeping it in the spreadsheet with the formulas.

For more info check here http://www.resolversystems.com/